# How to access html table on server side c# without using runat=server

Tags: c#, jquery, c#-4.0

I am creating dynamic rows on html table and trying to get table value on c#. but whenever I am putting `runat=server` on table jQuery doesn't work and hence I could not access html table on server side. Please give me some suggestion.

```
<table id="purchaseItems" name="purchaseItems" align="center">
    <tr>
        <th>Paragraph</th>
        <td>
            <input type="text" name="description[]" class="tbDescription next" required />
        </td>                               
        <td>
            <input type="button" name="addRow[]" class="add" value='+' />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="button" name="addRow[]" class="removeRow" value='-' />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and this is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(document).on('click', '#purchaseItems .add', function () {

    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    var clone = row.clone();

    // clear the values
    var tr = clone.closest('tr');
    tr.find('input[type=text]').val('');

    $(this).closest('tr').after(clone);

});

$(document).on('keypress', '#purchaseItems .next', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var v = $(this).index('input:text');
        var n = v + 1;
        $('input:text').eq(n).focus();
        //$(this).next().focus();
    }
});

$(document).on('keypress', '#purchaseItems .nextRow', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        $(this).closest('tr').find('.add').trigger('click');
        $(this).closest('tr').next().find('input:first').focus();
    }
});
$(document).on('click', '#purchaseItems .removeRow', function () {
    if ($('#purchaseItems .add').length > 1) {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    }
});
```

});

Comment: Put `runat=server` in your table and instead of `#purchaseItems`, use `#<%= purchaseItems.ClientID %>` to access table in jquery.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in ID, which generated by asp.net. After adding runat="server", it won't be simply purchaseItems. To get real ID, you should use next code:

```
$(document).on('keypress', '#<%= purchaseItems.ClientID %> .next', function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
        var v = $(this).index('input:text');
        var n = v + 1;
        $('input:text').eq(n).focus();
        //$(this).next().focus();
    }
});
```

But in this case, you won't be able to separate js and asp.net files. As alternative work around, you can use Dev Tools from any browser, to figure out which ID will be generated on client side.

Comment: Or simply put `ClientIDMode="Static"` - the server and client id will be the same, set by user.